# Android save network request state

Tags: java, android

I write my first android app, and now study Dmitry Kalita project - https://github.com/rusmonster/signin (project writen for e-legion android-develop course).

Project Structure looks like this:
**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity implements SignInModel.Observer {
    private SignInModel mSignInModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                mSignInModel.signIn(userName, password);
            }
        });
        //Восстановление SignInModel
        mSignInModel.registerObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mSignInModel.unregisterObserver(this);
        if (isFinishing()) {
            mSignInModel.stopSignIn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInStarted(final SignInModel signInModel) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded(final SignInModel signInModel) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed(final SignInModel signInModel) {
    }
}
```

**SignInModel.java**

```
public class SignInModel {
    private final SignInObservable mObservable = new SignInObservable();

    public void signIn(final String userName, final String password) {
        if (mIsWorking) {
            return;
        }
        mObservable.notifyStarted();
    }

    public void registerObserver(final Observer observer) {
        mObservable.registerObserver(observer);
        if (mIsWorking) {
            observer.onSignInStarted(this);
        }
    }

    public void unregisterObserver(final Observer observer) {
        mObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
    }

    private class SignInObservable extends Observable<Observer> {
        public void notifyStarted() {
            for (final Observer observer : mObservers) {
                observer.onSignInStarted(SignInModel.this);
            }
        }

        public void notifySucceeded() {
            for (final Observer observer : mObservers) {
                observer.onSignInSucceeded(SignInModel.this);
            }
        }

        public void notifyFailed() {
            for (final Observer observer : mObservers) {
                observer.onSignInFailed(SignInModel.this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in my project I have many network requests (eg photo and text info load in one activity), and I don't know how right make it under this architecture.

- make two models (one for photo load, one for info load).
- make it in
  one model, but should be know how from process executed now.

Please help me to choose right way.

P.S: I understand that this is not the best way, but it is quite simple, if you know a better way (not too difficult), then please tell me.

Comment: I think you should post this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that may help you get better answers.